# strings do not escape when use mysql_real_escape_string or addslashes in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

i use mysql_real_escape_string php function for escape data recieved from a form. my code for recieve form data is :

```
$std_id     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['std_id']);
$name       =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$family     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['family']);
```

for example if enter **O'reilly** string in name form field , this function work fine and my query done too.but when i go to mysql and my table , see that this string is inserted like **O'reilly** and not **O\'reilly**.
my query is :

```
$sql    =   "insert into student set 
            std_id  =   $std_id,
            name    =   '$name',
            family  =   '$family',
            ";
```

this happens when use addslashes() function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *exactly* what is supposed to happen. You want to insert the string `O'reilly` into the database, not `O\'reilly`, right?

The slashes merely tell MySQL that the next `'` is supposed to be a literal apostrophe, and not the apostrophe/single quote denoting the end of the string.

---

PS: You might want to consider using [PDO and prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), which offer a much cleaner syntax.

Comment: yes but already when i use this function for insert a value like **O'reilly** , it was inserted like **O'reilly** and i force to use **stripslashes()** function to strip \ character to show on a page correctly.

Comment: You should *not* have to use `stripslashes()`. If you see yourself forced to use it prior to outputting data, you are doing something wrong (like inserting escaped values into the database)

Comment: @Ahmad Just think about this for a second: `O\'reilly` is absolutely useless for you. You don't want to display that, so why would you want to store it that way?

Answer (score 2):

That's the point. `mysql_real_escape_string` is only there to make sure **the query syntax is correct**. This query syntax would be incorrect:

```
INSERT INTO ... name = 'O'Reilly'
```

The string terminator `'` is ambiguous/misplaced.
Escaped, this becomes:

```
INSERT INTO ... name = 'O\'Reilly'
```

Now the syntax is unambiguous, the `'` after `O` is *not* the string terminator, it's a literal value. That's all `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed to do. You do *not* want the value as "O\'Reilly" in your database, because that's garbage.

You should read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).